# Example of javascript validation on form controls before a postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback

I am designing a web-form to save some data. I am relatively new in this field .

Can someone give some exmamples of how to implement validations on form controls using javascript before a postback occurs.

Meaning, if the validations return true ( indicating some field missing ) then we don't do the postback and vice-versa.

Thanks,

Mangesh

Comment: thats a common question. google for it.

Comment: Were the examples you found by googling "javascript form validation tutorial" not suitable?

Comment: http://w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp - javascript validation which prevents form submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya you can use form with onSubmit function. as shown below

```
<form onsubmit="return Validate()">
... your controls will go here with submit button...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate() {
               do your validations here all goes well return true else return false        
    }
</script>
```

Hope this answered your question